# Combining different CASE expression syntaxes

Tags: sql, oracle

My understanding of a `CASE` expression you can use it for matching:

```
CASE expression
    WHEN first_option THEN some_value
    WHEN second_option THEN some_other_value
    ELSE default_value
END
```

and for evaluating conditions:

```
CASE
    WHEN a_value = another_value THEN some_result
    WHEN some_other_condition THEN some_other_result
    ELSE default_value
END
```

but can you combine both:

```
CASE expression
    WHEN first_option AND a_value = another_value THEN some_result
    WHEN second_option AND some_other_condition THEN some_other_result
    ELSE default value
END
```

For example, will this work?:

```
CASE btt_display
    WHEN 'COL' AND bd_trans_date = bd_posted_date THEN 'Y'
    WHEN 'DIS' AND bd_trans_date = bs_posted_date THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END as sda_ind
```

Comment: Try it and find out?  I honestly don't see the advantage of doing it this way - it just seems far more confusing.  Just do it as `Case When btt_display = 'COL' And bd_trans_date = bd_posted_date`...  The intent it perfectly clear that way, and it really isn't any more coding effort.  I honestly don't know if the hybrid will work or not (I've a strong feeling it won't), but seriously, you've already written it, just F5 it instead of asking the internet...

Comment: What is 'COL' supposed to represent? CASE uses a boolean comparison and that is not a comparison.

Comment: @JacobH `'COL'` is just the value of `btt_display` in his example

Comment: Ok I see now. I don't think combining the two methods will work. I am getting syntax errors attempting that hybrid. It fails with an OR clause too. Just use @Siyual syntax by having two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine them.  One expects a *value* after `WHEN`, the other a *condition*.

```
CASE column WHEN value
CASE WHEN condition
```

Attempting to combine them places a condition where a value is expected.